# Remove item from session

Tags: laravel, session

i have 2 function for my shopping cart,the first return total price and total qty of items:

```php
public function GetCartTotal(Request $request)
{
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return Response::json([null]);
    }
    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    return Response::json([
        'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice, 
        'totalQty' => $cart->totalQty]
    );
}

public function GetCartItems()
{
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return Response::json(['items' => null]);
    }
    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    return Response::json(['items' => $cart->items]);
}
```

this two function returns this two aray:

```
{
    totalPrice: 320750000,
    totalQty: 9
}
```

and:

```
{  
   items:{  
      1:{  
         id:1,
         qty:5,
         price:750000,
         item:{  
            id:1,
            name:"Product title 1",
            desc:null,
            price:"150000",
            barcode:"1556717299",
            Image:"1556717299.jpg",
            count:"25",
            created_at:"2019-05-01 17:58:19",
            updated_at:"2019-05-01 17:58:19"
         }
      },
      2:{  
         id:2,
         qty:4,
         price:320000000,
         item:{  
            id:2,
            name:"Product title 2",
            desc:null,
            price:"80000000",
            barcode:"1556729461",
            Image:"1556729461.jpg",
            count:"52",
            created_at:"2019-05-01 21:21:01",
            updated_at:"2019-05-01 21:21:01"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

i can destroy all cart session by this function:

```php
public function RemoveAllCartItems(){
    Session::forget('cart');
}
```

how can i delete specific cart items?
im using  this mehod,and its working.but its not change the totalprice and total qty:

```php
public function RemoveCartItem(Request $request, $id){
    $cart = Session::get('cart');
    unset($cart->items[$id]);
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the totalPrice and totalQty when you add an item? When you delete an item it also needs to subtract that from the totals.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by `pulling -> updating -> putting`

```
$cart = Session::pull('cart'); // Retrieve and delete an item
unset($cart->items[$id]);
// Add any additional logic that updates $cart (eg: updating qty and total price)
Session::put('cart', $cart);
```

Comment: this code have same problem not updating total qty and totl price